# Kotlin/ReactJS Task 'jsBrowserDevelopmentRun' not found

Tags: reactjs, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I just created a Kotlin/ReactJS project and am having a problem with gradle when trying to start the app. This is the error:

```
Task 'jsBrowserDevelopmentRun' not found in root project 'pentagono'. Some candidates are: 'browserDevelopmentRun'.
* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have not modified anything in build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 0):

This task is only available when using the multiplatform plugin. For pure Kotlin/JS applications, the task is named "browserDevelopmentRun".